# Center text between button

Tags: android

I have a header with two buttons and one textview one button is aligned left and the other one right. Now i'd like to center the text between these buttons. I am able to center everything vertically but fail to center the text horizontally between the buttons.

It currently look like this

:B:text  :B:

This is what I want

:B: text :B:

Comment: can you post the snippet of relevant code?

Comment: All I want is button 1 to be centered vertically and aligned left to parent, button 2 be centered vertically and aligned right to parent. Then a textview centered horizontally and vertically between these 2 buttons.

Comment: Use Relative Layout http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Some Text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wont the position of button2 be depending on the length of the textview?

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you are looking for.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="TextView" android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```